# Error en código PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Android usando phpMyAdmin para hacer una conexión con una base de datos. El gestor de MySql que uso es Xampp, y el código PHP que tengo para controlar el login en la aplicación es este:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "oftalmogestion_2_vot");
        
    $username = @$_POST["us_usuario"];
    $password = @$_POST["us_clave"];
    
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM td_usuario WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND us_ag_alias != '' ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $password, $username);
    
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  
    
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["username"] = $username;
        $response["password"] = $password;
    }
    
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Sin embargo, cuando intento ejecutar el código, salen esta cantidad de errores:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_store_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 12
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_fetch() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 17
> {"success":false}

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo? No entiendo porque me dice que se le está pasando un boolean en lugar de un statement.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Casi seguro que mysqli_prepare te esta devolviendo false. o falla la conexion o esta mal el SQL.. que base de datos usas? != me suena raro para una base de datos

Comment: Uso phpMyAdmin como gestor de bases de datos, y este código es para conectar mi aplicación en Android con una base de datos externa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que he escrito al menos 5 respuestas diciendo casi lo mismo en esta semana. La clave es **control estricto de tu código en todo momento**.

A tu código **le faltan tres evaluaciones** para ser un código normalizado y controlado, que haga lo que tú le digas que haga, no lo que él quiera hacer.

Te falta evaluar:

1. La conexión (`$con`)
2. Las variables `$username` y `$password`
3. La preparación de la sentencia `$statement`

No asumas que las cosas funcionarán normal siempre, evalúa cada eventualidad.

Si del otro lado se espera una respuesta JSON, pase lo que pase tienes que construir una respuesta de ese tipo.

Luego la manejas en el destino, leyendo el valor de `success` como bien estabas haciendo.

El siguiente código va evaluando y construyendo un array según lo que ocurra. De ese modo siempre tendrás una respuesta. En caso de `error` leyendo esa clave del array sabrás lo que ha ocurrido del lado del servidor.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "oftalmogestion_2_vot");

    /*1. Evaluar conexión*/
    if ($con){
        $username = $_POST["us_usuario"]; //Usar @ es una mala práctica
        $password = $_POST["us_clave"];

        /*2. Evaluar user y pwd*/
        if ($username != '' && $pasword  != ''){

            $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM td_usuario WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND us_ag_alias != '' ");
            /* 3. Evaluar statement*/
            if ($statement){
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

                mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $password, $username);

                $arrRespuesta = array();

                while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
                    $arrRespuesta["success"] = true;
                    $arrRespuesta["username"] = $username;
                    $arrRespuesta["password"] = $password;
                }

            }else{

                $arrRespuesta=array("success"=>false, "msg"=>"Falló la preparación de la consulta");

            }           

        }else{

            $arrRespuesta=array("success"=>false, "msg"=>"user y/o password vacíos");

        }

    }else{

        $arrRespuesta=array("success"=>false, "msg"=>"No se pudo conectar a la base de datos");
    }

    header("Content-type:application/json") ; //Olvidaba esto que es muy importante
    echo json_encode($arrRespuesta);
?>
```

Comment: Después de probar tu código me salen ahora estos errores:

Notice: Undefined index: us_usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: us_clave in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login.php on line 6

¿Podría deberse a que la conexión a la base de datos esté mal hecha por mi parte?

Comment: @G.Corporales ahora entenderás el comentario hecho aquí: `$username = $_POST["us_usuario"]; //Usar @ es una mala práctica`. Cuando usas `@` no te notifica de posibles fallos en tu código, al quitarlo te notifica que las dos variables del POST no existen, sea porque sus inputs (en el HTML) no tienen una etiqueta `name` llamada `us_usuario` y `us_clave` respectivamente, sea porque no las estás enviando por POST. O sea, la URL de la petición debe ser así más o menos `tu-archivo.php?us_usuario=1&us_password=123456`

Comment: La URL de la petición debe ser así más o menos `http://www.tudominio.com/tu-archivo.php?us_usuario=1&us_clave=123456`

Comment: ¿Dónde tendría que poner la URL de petición? Esta página de php la estoy usando para conectar un servidor en phpMyAdmin para que una aplicación de Android conecte con una base de datos, y según los tutoriales que he estado siguiendo con el código que originalmente pasé debería funcionar (Evidentemente no lo ha hecho, por eso he preguntado aquí)

Comment: No sé qué tutoriales has seguido, uno de los mejores es [este](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/10/servicio-web-restful-android-php-mysql-json/). Te explica paso por paso cómo funciona. En teoría, desde Android, tú envías una petición al servidor. Si la BD está en el dominio `tu-dominio.com`. Tienes que enviar desde Android una petición con algo como esto: `http://www.tu-dominio.com/tu-archivo.php?us_usuario=1&us_clave=123456`  o lo puedes hacer más elegante, en forma de API: `http://www.tu-dominio.com/insertar/us_usuario=1/us_clave=123456` La segunda opción requeriría redirecciones.

Comment: Sería en realidad un servicio REST o una API. Lo podrías probar desde el navegador mismo, sin necesidad de Android, poniendo la URL correcta: `http://www.tu-dominio.com/tu-archivo.php?us_usuario=1&us_cla‌​ve=123456`. Cuando haces esto en tu código: `$username = $_POST["us_usuario"];  $password = $_POST["us_clave"];` lo que haces es recuperar los valores `1` y `123456` pasados en la URL.  Lo puedes probar desde el navegador, verás que te da una respuesta JSON.

Comment: El **[enlace anterior](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/10/servicio-web-restful-android-php-mysql-json/)** te muestra cómo construir un servicio REST bien hecho, con direcciones elegantes, tipo API, y **[este enlace](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-volley-peticiones-http/)** te muestra cómo hacer las peticiones a ese servicio usando Volley. Siguiendo ambos tutoriales he podido construir el servicio REST de mi app Android, que devuelve una respuesta JSON: http://deiverbum.org/api/beta/oficio/20170929 Hay un archivo PHP que recibe todas las peticiones y las maneja.

Comment: Conseguí solucionarlo, gracias por tu tiempo y por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Revisando la documentación de la función **mysqli_prepare** en http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php especifica bien claramente que ella devuelve un objeto instancia de la clase mysqli_stmt **SI NO HAY ERRORES**, de lo contrario devuelve **false**, si antes de ejecutar el **mysqli_stmt_bind_result()** y pasarle la variable **$statement** haces un var_dump($statement) verás lo que te digo. Ahora, la cuestión es ver porque te está dando error a la hora de preparar la consulta, revisa que la conexión esté bien, que la clave, el usuario, la base de datos sea la que realmente tienes en el servidor. Otra recomendación que te haría es usar esas mismas funciones pero orientado a objeto:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "Amersfoort";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```